# Изменение шрифта заголовка и отображение данных в процентах QtChart.QChartView

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qchartview

Требуется изменить шрифт заголовка и сделать так, чтобы показывалась доля каждого сектора в процентах

```
import sys
import random
from typing import List, Optional, Union

from PyQt5 import QtChart, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

class PieChartConstructor(QtChart.QChartView):

    def __init__(self, series: List[QtChart.QPieSeries], title: Optional[str] = None) -> None:

        self.series = series
        print(series.slices())

        # for slice in self.series.slices():
        #     slice.setLabel("{:.2f}%".format(100 * slice.percentage()))

        self.title = "Статистика по операциям"

        header_font = QFont('Sergoe UI', 12)
        header_font.setWeight(QFont.Bold)

        chart = QtChart.QChart()
        chart.addSeries(self.series)

        # chart.legend().hide()
        # chart.createDefaultAxes()

        chart.setTitle(self.title)

        chart.setAnimationOptions(QtChart.QChart.SeriesAnimations)

        # chart.legend().setVisible(True)
        chart.legend().setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        chart.legend().setFont(header_font)
        #chart.title.setFont(header_font)

        super().__init__(chart)
        self.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

    def add_slice(self, slice: Union[int, QtChart.QPieSlice], change_color: bool = True) -> None:
        if isinstance(slice, int):
            slice: QtChart.QPieSlice = self.series.slices()[slice]

        slice.setExploded(True)
        slice.setLabelVisible(True)

        if change_color:

            # цвет и толщина контура
            slice.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 1))
            slice.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.green)

    def update_series(self, slice: QtChart.QPieSlice) -> None:

        slice.setValue(slice.value() + random.randint(-2, 2))

    def slice_clicked(self, slice: QtChart.QPieSlice) -> None:

        exploded = slice.isExploded()

        for s in self.series.slices():

            if s.isExploded():
                s.setExploded(False)
                s.setLabelVisible(False)

        if not exploded:
            self.add_slice(slice, change_color=False)


class PieChartExample(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self) -> None:

        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Время выполнения операций")
        self.setMinimumSize(700, 500)
        chartview = self.create_piechart()
        self.setCentralWidget(chartview)
        chartview.series.hovered.connect(chartview.update_series)
        chartview.series.clicked.connect(chartview.slice_clicked)

    def bla(self):
        self.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {random.choice(['lightgrey', '#432', 'white', 'grey'])};")

    def create_piechart(self) -> QtChart.QChartView:

        series = QtChart.QPieSeries()
        [series.append(*piece) for piece in data]
        pie = PieChartConstructor(series)
        pie.add_slice(0)
        return pie


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PieChartExample()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
import random
from typing import List, Optional, Union

from PyQt5 import QtChart, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

class PieChartConstructor(QtChart.QChartView):
    def __init__(self, series: List[QtChart.QPieSeries], title: Optional[str] = None) -> None:

        self.series = series
        #print(series.slices())

        # for slice in self.series.slices():
        #     slice.setLabel("{:.2f}%".format(100 * slice.percentage()))

        self.title = "<span style='color: red; font-size: 22pt;'>Статистика по операциям</span>"

        header_font = QFont('Sergoe UI', 12)
        header_font.setWeight(QFont.Bold)

        chart = QtChart.QChart()
        chart.addSeries(self.series)

        # chart.legend().hide()
        # chart.createDefaultAxes()

        chart.setTitle(self.title)

        chart.setAnimationOptions(QtChart.QChart.SeriesAnimations)

        # chart.legend().setVisible(True)
        chart.legend().setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        chart.legend().setFont(header_font)
        #chart.title.setFont(header_font)

        super().__init__(chart)
        self.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

    def add_slice(self, slice: Union[int, QtChart.QPieSlice], change_color: bool = True) -> None:
        if isinstance(slice, int):
            slice: QtChart.QPieSlice = self.series.slices()[slice]
        slice.setExploded(True)
        slice.setLabelVisible(True)

        if change_color:
            # цвет и толщина контура
            slice.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 1))
            slice.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.green)

    def update_series(self, slice: QtChart.QPieSlice) -> None:
        slice.setValue(slice.value() + random.randint(-2, 2))

    def slice_clicked(self, slice: QtChart.QPieSlice) -> None:
        exploded = slice.isExploded()

        for s in self.series.slices():

            if s.isExploded():
                s.setExploded(False)
                s.setLabelVisible(False)

        if not exploded:
            self.add_slice(slice, change_color=False)


class PieChartExample(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Время выполнения операций")
        self.setMinimumSize(700, 500)
        chartview = self.create_piechart()
        self.setCentralWidget(chartview)
        chartview.series.hovered.connect(chartview.update_series)
        chartview.series.clicked.connect(chartview.slice_clicked)

    def bla(self):
        self.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {random.choice(['lightgrey', '#432', 'white', 'grey'])};")

    def create_piechart(self) -> QtChart.QChartView:
        series = QtChart.QPieSeries()
# NameError: name 'data' is not defined             ???
#        [series.append(*piece) for piece in data]  ???
        [series.append(*piece) for piece in [[f'item_1 {15}%', 15], 
                                             [f'item_2 {33}%', 33], 
                                             [f'item_3 {52}%', 52],
                                            ]]
        pie = PieChartConstructor(series)
        pie.add_slice(0)
        return pie


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PieChartExample()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> А чтобы значения в процентах показывались на диаграмме, а не в легенде?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QChartView, QPieSeries, QPieSlice
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        series = QPieSeries()
        series.append("Python", 80)
        series.append("C++", 70)
        series.append("Java", 50)
        series.append("C#", 40)
        series.append("PHP", 30)
        series.setLabelsVisible(True)
    
        series.setLabelsPosition(QPieSlice.LabelInsideHorizontal)
        for slice in series.slices():
            slice.setLabel("<h3>{:.2f}%</h3>".format(100 * slice.percentage()))

        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.createDefaultAxes()
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)
        chart.setTitle("Pie Chart Example")
        chart.legend().setVisible(True)
        chart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)

        chart.legend().markers(series)[0].setLabel("Python")
        chart.legend().markers(series)[1].setLabel("C++")
        chart.legend().markers(series)[2].setLabel("Java")
        chart.legend().markers(series)[3].setLabel("C#")
        chart.legend().markers(series)[4].setLabel("PHP")

        chartview = QChartView(chart)
        chartview.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.setCentralWidget(chartview)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setWindowTitle("PyQtChart Pie Chart")
    window.resize(700, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чтобы значения в процентах показывались на диаграмме, а не в легенде?

Comment: @follow_the_sun Я обновил свой ответ. Если мои ответы учат вас чему-то новому - не стесняйтесь отмечать их и как полезные.